# PHP: Accents does not working

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm hosting a website on [CPanel](https://cpanel.com/) and I've already done the proper configurations, however, the accents does not work.

php.init, `default_charset = "utf-8"` is enabled, my index.php file has the meta charset defined, also I wrote this PHP header.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Responder Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 21:38:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Is there anything more that I should do?

Comment: where's the text coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, you mean where's the accent??

Comment: is the text hard coded in the file? from a database? other ?

Comment: It's a text in a form. like: <input type=text name='úaré'>